назывные предложения в составе придаточных
Может ли назывное односоставное быть в придаточной части предложения? Может ли оно быть в главной части сложноподчиненного предложения?
Про односоставные со сказуемым все ясно, они могут стоять и там и там.

«Может ли оно быть в главной части придаточного предложения?» === Наверное, Вы хотели написать так: «…в главной части сложноподчинённого предложения» ❓

КРАТКАЯ ТЕОРИЯ
О номинативных (назывных) предложениях

ОСНОВНОЙ ПРИЗНАК

Утверждается наличие или существование предметов, явлений, состояний.

ГРАММАТИЧЕСКАЯ ФОРМА

(1) Собственно-бытийные предложения: Мороз. Темная ночь. Озеро. Ночь. Весна. Тишина и спокойствие. Много снега.
Сравнить: Была ночь (двусоставное предложение).
ВОЗМОЖНО НАЛИЧИЕ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ: Горы с иссиня-снежными шапками.
Цветы в вазе (но: в вазе – цветы, двусоставное предложение).
(2) Указательные (обозначают вхождение предмета в поле зрения говорящего): Вот и озеро. Вот он, тысяча девятьсот шестнадцатый год!
(3) Оценочно-бытийные (с восклицательными частицами): Что за край! Никак гроза?
(4) Событийные назывные предложения (обозначают отрезки времени, события в фиксированном настоящем времени): Ночь. Зима. Жара.

ДЕЙСТВУЮЩЕЕ ЛИЦО, ХАРАКТЕР ДЕЙСТВИЯ

Главный член выражен сущ. или словосочетанием в И.п.
Только настоящее время!
Допускается распространение предмета определением (согласованным или несогласованным), но детерминант (обстоятельство или дополнение) невозможен.

ОБЛАСТЬ ПРИМЕНЕНИЯ

Описание местности, сценические ремарки, личные переживания, воспоминания, краткое описание внешности.
Это то, что видит перед собой автор. Особый ИЗОБРАЗИТЕЛЬНЫЙ ПРИЕМ: сообщается не только о наличии предмета, но и о том, что он находится в ПОЛЕ ЗРЕНИЯ автора. Автор мысленно переносится в то же время и видит предмет «сейчас».
РЕШЕНИЕ
Можно составить СПП с придаточным определительным, в главной части которого будет назывное предложение, например:
День, который  мне особенно запомнился...  Он начинался совсем обыкновенно, и ничего в нем не предвещало будущих удивительных событий.
Таким образом,  назывной может быть только главная часть, а придаточное может быть только определительным. Это соответствует структуре назывного предложения с обычным определением.

Sharon, мне непонятно, чем отличается "Ночь" из пункта "Собственно-бытийные" от "Ночь" из "Событийные назывные", ну и все остальные Морозы.

Если наблюдатель описывает событие в фиксированный момент, то это бытийное предложение.  Ночь. Время как бы остановилось. // Если наблюдатель рассматривает отрезок времени, то назывное предложение относится ко всему отрезку. События происходят ночью.

??? Вопросов стало больше. :))

У Кустовой смотрела. Что именно непонятно?  Ночь. Наблюдатель любуется  звездным небом, оно кажется ему прекрасным.  // Ночь.  Но лесная жизнь только начинается. Вот зайчик пробежал...
